# Jackson XML: nested field deserialization

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have the following xml

```
<MyPojo>
  <name>Jason</name>
  <age>25</age>
  <meta>
    <occupation>Engineer</occupation>
  </meta>
</MyPojo>
```

I need to deserialize it to the following POJO:

```
public class MyPojo {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String occupation;
}
```

The problem here is that `occupation` is wrapped within `meta` element

Comment: you need to create class meta. in that you must have field occupation.

Answer (score 7):

You need one more object:

```
public class MyPojo {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Meta meta;
}

public class Meta{
    private String occupation;
}
```

Comment: is this the only way?

Comment: @user1745356 as i know yes

Answer (score 2):

My idea is to replace `occupation` with an own class. Something like myMeta or whatever you want to call it(be aware in your case like the xml says: meta). This class should cotain the field occupation:

```
   public class Meta
   {
       private String occupation;
   }
```

After that you only have to add a new field of your new class e.g. `myMeta` to `myPojo`. Something like this:

```
   public class MyPojo
   {
       private String name;
       private int age;
       private Meta meta;
   }
```

this should avoid

> that occupation is wrapped within meta element

Hope that helps!